# Converting MysQl Time to decimal format

Tags: php, undefined-function

I'm trying to convert Time format `00:00:00` to decimal `0.00`.

I tried this:

```
<?php 
   $hourswork_wk1 = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
   $decimalHourswk1 = decimalHours($hourswork_wk1);
   decimalHours();

    function decimalHours($timewk1)
    {
        $hourswork_wk1 = explode(":", $timewk1);
        return ($hourswork_wk1[0] + ($hourswork_wk1[1]/60) + ($hourswork_wk1[2]/3600));
        echo $decimalHours
    }


;?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
   $hourswork_wk1 = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
   $decimalHourswk1 = decimalHours($hourswork_wk1);

    function decimalHours($timewk1)
    {
        $hourswork_wk1 = explode(":", $timewk1);
        return ($hourswork_wk1[0] + ($hourswork_wk1[1]/60) + ($hourswork_wk1[2]/3600));

    }
?>
```

I get a call to undefined function decimalHours() error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Putting `echo` after `return` makes no sense. The `return` statement ends the function.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `decimalHours()`

Comment: Why do you have the line `decimalHours()`? It doesn't do anything, and it's invalid syntax.

Comment: @Barmar: True true. Thank you for pointing that out. I made the edit.

Comment: The code works fine for me.

Comment: @Barmar: Very bizarre... I'm trying to echo the value that was returned and it still gives me undefined  function()? Did you do anything different?

Comment: The only difference is how I assigned to `$hourswork_wk1`. See http://ideone.com/U7Gzxb

Comment: @Barmar: Wow the IDE is simply not letting the code pass no matter what. The undefined error remains. I'm going to have to look for another solution to convert time to decimals.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the IDE, not the code. What happens when you run it on the server?

Comment: What IDE is it?

Comment: @Barmar: I'm using good'ol Netbeans.

Comment: I can't find anyone else complaining that Netbeans gives spurious errors like this. Make sure you don't have a typo.

Comment: @Barmar: well I mean im copying the code as it is... It never happens to me. But im going over it right now.

Comment: @Barmar: I had to look for an alternative. It works now posted the answer. Thanks for your time anyway dude.

Answer (score 0):

Alright for some reason the code I have written never worked for me. So after looking around for something more tangible I stumbled upon [Philip Norton code](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/converting-and-decimal-time-php) which works like a charm with dynamic variables. Suit yourself.

**script**

```
<?php
//$week1hours = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
$week1hours = "14:33:38";
function time_to_decimal($time) {
    $timeArr = explode(':', $time);
    $decTime = ($timeArr[0] + ($timeArr[1]/60) + ($timeArr[2]/3600));
    return $decTime;
}
echo time_to_decimal($week1hours);
?>
```

**result**

```
14.560555555556
```

**bonus : limit to 2 decimals**

Use round to only get 2 decimals

```
<?php
//$week1hours = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
$week1hours = "14:33:38";
function time_to_decimal($time) {
    $timeArr = explode(':', $time);
    $decTime = ($timeArr[0] + ($timeArr[1]/60) + ($timeArr[2]/3600));
    return $decTime;
}
$totalhours= time_to_decimal($week1hours);
echo round($totalhours, 2);
?>
```

**result**

```
14.56
```

Comment: Other than the name of the function, what's the difference?

Comment: @Barmar: I'm puzzled I have no idea. I wish I could tell.

Comment: Maybe Netbeans doesn't like you calling a function before you define it? PHP itself has no problem with this.

Comment: That might be why. I need to look more into that a bit later.